# Map values are not retaining on rerender

Tags: apex, visualforce, rerender

i created a page

```
<apex:page controller="Sample1" action="{!NumberOfSteps}">
<apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.jszip, '/jszip.js')}"/>
    <apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.jszip, '/jszip-load.js')}"/>
    <apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.jszip, '/jszip-deflate.js')}"/>
    <apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.jszip, '/jszip-inflate.js')}"/>
<apex:outputPanel layout="block" style="height:100px;background-color:#{!xx.Header_Color__c}" > 
<apex:outputText style="font-size:250%;margin:10px;" value="{!xx.Tag_Line__c}"></apex:outputText>
</apex:outputPanel>
<apex:dynamicComponent componentValue="{!flow}" />
<apex:form >
<apex:outputPanel layout="block" style="height:100px;background-color:#{!xx.Footer_Color__c}" />
<apex:outputPanel id="ddff" />
<apex:outputPanel id="flowPanel">
<apex:outputPanel rendered="{!NOT(rendering)}">
<apex:actionFunction name="receiveFile" action="{!receiveMetadataZipFile}" rerender="ddff" oncomplete="unzip();">
      <apex:param name="filename" assignTo="{!MetadataFileName}" value=""/>
      <apex:param name="filedata" assignTo="{!MetadataFileData}" value=""/>
</apex:actionFunction>  
 <apex:actionFunction name="receiveComplete" action="{!receiveComplete}" rerender="flowPanel" />
 <c:unzip name="unzip" oncomplete="if(more) receiveFile(path, data); else receiveComplete();">{!MetaDataRetrieveZip}</c:unzip>

</apex:outputPanel>
</apex:outputPanel>

<apex:actionPoller interval="5" action="{!checkStatus}" rendered="{!rendering}" rerender="flowPanel" />
</apex:outputPanel>
</apex:form>
<script>
</script>
</apex:page>
```

and apex class is

```
public class Sample1 {
    public Dynamic_Flow__c xx{get;set;}
    public Map<String,List<String>> flowMap;
    public Sample1(){
        Dynamic_Flow_Settings__c x =  Dynamic_Flow_Settings__c.getInstance();
        xx = [Select Id,Header_Color__c,Footer_Color__c,Background_Color__c,Flow_Name__c,Tag_Line__c  From Dynamic_Flow__c Where Id = :x.Dynamic_Flow_Id__c];
        MetadataFiles = new List<MetadataFile>();
        //flow = new Component.Flow.interview();
        //flow.name='Calculator';
        activeVersion =false;
        System.debug('coming hhhere');
        flowMap = new Map<String,List<String>>();
    }
    public void NumberOfSteps(){
        System.debug('FlowMap is'+flowMap);
    }
```

at end of NumberOfSteps in which flowMap is not blank but after when check status is called Map is {} in debug logs but xx is not blank.its the same value that is assigned in constructor.Please tell why map values are getting blank ??

Comment: every public field is retaining its value except this Map field.is there anything exception with map ??

Comment: Map values act like any other controller field values: they can be retained. The code you have posted sets flowMap to be an empty map in the constructor and because apex:actionFunction and apex:actionPoller restore the view state in the controller before their target methods run that empty map should always be restored. You don't show any code that adds values to flowMap so "Please tell why map values are getting blank ??" is not answerable.

Answer (score 2):

The reason why your maps are not returning is this data is not cached as your map is populated in the Constructor and once action methods are called constructor dont get invoked .Try forming the map in action method itself .When action methods invoke and Re Render constructor don't get called again.

You can write the utility to populate map and call in action method as well as constructor .